# What does "half weighted" mean in this context?

Tags: terminology, volatility

The flip side of a strong dollar is weakness in other currencies. The U.S. dollar index is about half weighted in the Euro, and that unit broke down to multiyear lows. However, the Euro has been declining, albeit with volatility, since 2008 (see Chart 3).

Comment: Telling us where this was quoted from would be both helpful and polite to the author...

Comment: @keshlam http://www.barrons.com/articles/what-the-strong-dollar-means-for-investors-1482406521

Answer (score 5, accepted):

US Dollar Index consists of:

- Euro (EUR), **57.6%** weight
- Japanese yen (JPY), 13.6% weight
- Pound sterling (GBP), 11.9% weight
- Canadian dollar (CAD), 9.1% weight
- Swedish krona (SEK), 4.2% weight
- Swiss franc (CHF) 3.6% weight